# Microservice architectural clarification

Tags: c#, microservices

I have a microservice architectured application. Where i have a CompanyService, an OrderService and a TransactionSevice. A user logs in and he can load all orders for his company. So the order has a CompanyId. Then it loads all Transactions for that order, so the transaction has an OrderId. I am going through some security thoughts. How can i make sure that the user only loads or saves transactions for the orders that belong to his company. I mean the TransactionService should not need to know about the Company (CompanyId). Is it something i should check just before saving? Eg check that the orderid belongs to the company or is there some other pattern?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a perfect use case where splitting the functionality up into microservices is not appropriate. Doubly so if all the data is actually being loaded from the same database. If we supposed, for a moment, that the split *was* somehow meaningful or necessary, then apparently services need a way to authenticate users (via some sort of token-based infrastructure, probably) and a way to verify access to individual records without relying on other services. The latter, in particular, becomes very awkward if you can't exploit the natural relationships.

Comment: To second @JeroenMostert's comment, you should only split things into separate services (micro or not) if it is possible for them to perform their jobs while the other services (and those services' data) are unavailable. If that's not practical, don't split them.

Comment: You are both right but, going down the path of microservices you will always end up in the situation that you break DB models apart and will not be able to relay on FK so this kind of problem will always occur. Otherwise you will always be stuck with one big monolithic database. I am now implementing Azure AD B2C, this way I can add custom attributes to the user and retrieve its information inside the microservice as well.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts:

Your first microservice is going to be

```
GetOrders(int userId)
```

In it you need to do a check for which company to pull by userId

Your second call is going to be

```
GetTransactions(int orderId)
```

Depending on how much security you want, you can also do:

```
GetTransactions(int orderId, int userId)
```

To back check that the user making the call belongs to the correct company in case of API abuse.  So basically, yes you have to check that the user belongs to the company that they are getting the transaction for.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. That was exactly what I had in mind. So I guess I was not that far off with my design. Thankss

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer to add some level of orchestration, via an interface service for the user interaction with the other services... which has tradeoffs, like potentially creating a bottleneck and a single-point-of-failure.

That interface/proxy service for the user could enforce the right use of the API.

Another option, as mentioned in other answers, is to use internally a token, but every other service may have to verify that token with the authentication service, and then use the userId to request data from other services.

Comment: You could also check the validity of the token (verify signature and expiry,date & time), without calling the authentication service each time. But of course it's less secured (you can't revoke a token immediately).